# Difference between "civic rights" and "civil rights"

Tags: differences

Is there any difference in meaning between the term "civic rights" and the term "civil rights"? Or are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: Civil rights are obviously the rights of a common man including the politicians while civic rights can also be referred to as political rights which may or may not apply to a common man.Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think there are "civic rights"; only "civil."

Answer (score 4):

According to the *Grammarist*, the terms Civic and Civil are defined as follows:

> **Civic** is an adjective which describes an object or person as having to do with a city or town, or that the object was created or came from a city or town. It specifically has to do with the government of a city or the duties involved with running a city.
>
> **Civil** is an adjective describing an object or a person relating to
>   citizenship or a citizen (i.e., a member of the community) as opposed
>   to the military or church leadership. Civil rights are things that
>   every person of the community has the right to. This term is not
>   discussing human rights, which are things each human on Earth is
>   entitled to, without the need to be a member of a community.

The term *Civic Rights* would have limited use with regard to an individual citizen.  As to whether the two terms, *Civil Rights* and *Civic Rights*, are interchangeable, they are not in most cases.  *Civic* applies to rights as a member/official with regard to their community.  *Civil* applies to inalienable rights of the person.

Comment: My upvote. Civic responsibility/civic duties sound better than civic rights.